# Confused on covariant derivative vs affine connection

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, connections

I am studying differential geometry and I recently learned about affine connections. My understanding of them so far is that they are a generalization of the directional derivative to arbitrary manifolds and allows us to differentiate a vector field in the direction of another vector field. They are needed as we otherwise cannot compare tangent vectors that belong to different tangent spaces. As a consequence, the covariant derivative thus lets us "connects" various tangent spaces together.

With this in mind, I am confused on what new idea the covariant derivative is trying to capture. It seems that is is also differentiating a vector field with respect to another vector field (or a vector field that is defined using a curve). I am having a hard time understanding what the covariant derivative is really doing that an affine connection is not already doing. What does it intuitively mean for a covariant derivative to be compatible with an affine connection?

Comment: They are the same thing.  A connection is $\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E\otimes T^*M)$, whereas a covariant derivative is $\mathfrak{X}(M)\otimes\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)$.

Comment: Either way, they provide a way to define the directional derivative of a vector field (or a section of a vector bundle if you know what that is) at a point. And their definitions are exactly the same.

Comment: @Deane Thank you for your comment, if they are the same object is there any reason they have different names? Do they generalize differently?

Comment: @user10354138 This is interesting, so they are the same map but the covariant derivative requires you to also define the vector field which it is being taken over?

Comment: A covariant derivative, i.e., affine connection should be thought of a way to define the directional derivative of a section of a vector bundle $E$. In other words, given a section $s$ of $E$ over $M$ and a tangent vector $v \in T_pM$, the covariant derivative of $s$ at $p \in M$ in the direction $v$ is denoted $\nabla_vs(p)$ and satisfies various properties. Specifically, given $v \in T_pM$, $s\in \Gamma(E) \mapsto \nabla_vs(p)$ is a derivation, and given $s\in\Gamma(E)$, $v\in T_pM\mapsto \nabla_vs(p)$ is linear.

Comment: @Deane I see, in this case it seems the covariant derivative really is the same thing as an affine connection. However I am still confused on why we bother defining the covariant derivative if we already have affine connections.

Comment: @CBBAM, the concept was probably developed independently by two different groups of mathematicians, who named it differently. This kind of redundancy is common in math, especially with mathematical notation.

Comment: @Deane Got it, thank you for all your help!

Comment: The concept was developed by at least **three** different mathematicians: E.Cartan, Ehresmann, Koszul, who used different formalism for this concept.